# Query performance of a SELECT statement using WHERE and NOT IN

Tags: performance, mysql, sql

Can anyone help improve the performance of my query?  When I run it, it locks the database for 5 to 10 minutes.

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    u.email, 
    u.created_at, 
    p.firstname, 
    p.lastname, 
    p.address, 
    p.address_2, 
    p.city, 
    p.country, 
    p.state, 
    p.zip, 
    p.phone, 
    p.phone_2, 
    u.last_ip, 
    u.last_login_at, 
    u.auto_login, 
    u.registration_page,
    s.product_name
    FROM
    users AS u
        Left Join subscriptions AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
        Left Join profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
    where u.registration_page='Chris_Cleanse' and
        u.id not in (select user_id from goal_sheets) and 
        u.id not in(select user_id from sheet_user_popup_not_adam) and 
        s.expired=TRUE ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

[Here is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obub6.png):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything unreasonable about the query itself.

However, if I'm interpreting the output of `EXPLAIN` correctly, the anti-join with `sheet_user_popup_not_adam` is being done using a full table scan.  Run

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM sheet_user_popup_not_adam;
```

If no index exists on the `user_id` column, then run

```
CREATE INDEX sheet_user_popup_not_adam_user_id ON sheet_user_popup_not_adam (user_id);
```

Maybe that should be `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX …` instead, if appropriate.  Hopefully the performance should improve after you create the index.

Comment: On further thought, could you post the output of `SHOW INDEXES` for all of the tables in this query? In particular, I'm curious about `SHOW INDEXES FROM subscriptions`, and why the query planner acts as it does.